# Command Line outputs does not show up

Tags: c#, cmd

I wrote an MP3 conversion application which uses the `ffmpeg` encoder executable. When I just send the `-h (help)` argument to it, I can get all of the outputs to my txt file. But when I try to send the actual conversion arguments, the command works as expected but I can not get the output lines.

Here is my snippet:

```
/* Success */
string ffmpeg_cmd = "ffmpeg -h";    

/* Below command works well, but it's not able to get the output */
//string ffmpeg_cmd = "ffmpeg -i inputFile.wav -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 320k -f mp3 -y outputFile.mp3";  

Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(ffmpeg_cmd /* + " & exit" */);    //"ping bing.com"

string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

File.AppendAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\cmd_logs.txt", output );

cmd.WaitForExit();
```

As I said, both command work as expected. The problem is only the second one can not get the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ffmpeg.exe -i REMINDER.WAV -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 320k -f mp3 -y REMINDER.mp3 2>>cmd_logs.txt";
cmd.Start();

cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Edit::
You may also use -report option to generate log of `ffmpeg.exe`

**Update**:

`ffmpeg` uses `StandardOutput` to create binary output file. In your case `MP3`. For logs, it use `StandardError` stream. You can make your code working by making `RedirectStandardError = true` and by reading `cmd.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`.

One more thing. you can use `cmd.StartInfo.Arguments` option to pass parameters instead of using input redirection. And if you are calling it through `CMD`, use `/c` option too. Otherwise command window will not be terminated automatically.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would describe how this is different than the OP code and why it will work.

Comment: That extra option works but actually the ffmpeg is the one handles the log operation in your example. I still don't understand why I can not read the output.

Comment: ffmpeg uses StandardOutput to create binary output file. In your case MP3. For logs, it use StandardError stream. You can make your code working by making RedirectStandardError = true and by reading cmd.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

Comment: one more thing. you can use "cmd.StartInfo.Arguments" option to pass parameters instead of using input redirection. And if you are calling it through CMD, use /c option too. Otherwise command window will not be terminated automatically.